# How can I calculate these capacitor values?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, switching-regulator

I’m trying to build a fan controller. My power source is a +24 V battery which is commonly used in cars.

I want use a [regulator module (buck step-down regulator based on the CN3903)](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256802981451656.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt&_randl_shipto=US).

This is my schematic:

[image: Regulator Part]

[EDIT : wrong cap number]
**C4**: for +24 V battery input ripple
**C9**: for +5 V output ripple

[image: Fan Motor Part]

How can I calculate the capacitor values when drawing a circuit using these regulator modules?

If I have an oscilloscope, do I apply the required maximum load and set it to the maximum noise and ripple-free value?

Comment: Where did this schematic come from? As drawn this circuit will run the fan constantly. If FAN1 is indeed drawing 3A average, D1 is also going to get very hot, burning several watts and probably going to melt.

Comment: The SS34 has a maximum forward current of 3A so it's not really suitable anyway.

Comment: sorry i had a mistake
i uploaded wrong file

Comment: There are no such caps in the image that you refer to in the text. Also, what caps you need to use depends on what your regulator module needs, if any, and what your other module needs, if any. Was there a manual or schematic of products available?

Comment: Everything given in the datasheet: http://www.dcx-ic.com/uploads/soft/210625/1-210625131439.pdf so what exactly is your question?

Comment: The value of the capacitor recommended by Datasheet of 'CN3903' is different from the value of the capacitor of CN3903 regulator module I purchased.

Then can I just use it as it is?
Or should I add an additional capacitor?

because I looked for circuits using a regulator based on CN3903
Capacitor values are different from those of the circuit diagram

So I think I need to change or add the capacitor value according to my circuit.

Comment: @datenheim That data sheet is for the regulator chip itself used on the module. That has nothing to do with the fully assembled module that contains that chip and assorted amount of unknown components.

Comment: you mean that many of these modules can be used as they are, right?
In the case of an environment that consumes a positive amount of power, i can minimize ripple by increasing the capacitor value
and if it's a noisy environment, I should add an inductor?

Comment: _”maximum noise and ripple-free value”_ Why? That would require infinite filtering.

Comment: @Justme: the datasheet nevertheless explains how the capacitor values are determined. One can measure whats on the board and add caps if that improves something. Surely several boards use varying caps and thus have different ripple voltages etc. Also not all modules may reach the maximum power possible with the IC itself.

Comment: @datenheim That's why you would need the data sheet of the module. Or schematics. So you don't need to remove the capacitors to be able to measure them. You could also just not add any extra capacitors and see if it works. If it powers a fan controller then what difference it makes how much ripple there is if the fan controller can work with it. Ending up with no ripple means infinite capacitance. Small ripple is allowed.

Comment: Well, the original question was about calculating the capacitor values, and those formulas are in the datasheet of the ic.

Comment: @datenheim No, that is not what the question asked - the question asked how much the module needs capacitance outside the module, not how much the chip on the module need in general. There is no formula for calculating how much extra capacitance should be added in addition to what the module already contains. There is also no manual of the module if it requires external caps and of which type. And what good are external electrolytic capacitors which are very poor capacitors compared to the ceramic capacitors already onboard the module.

Comment: Thank you! will follow the datasheet.
i have to consider a lot of other things about capacitors, including PCB design and parts manufacturer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only require 5V / 100 mA nearly any module using this chip, whatever capacitors it has from the manufacturer, would be up to the task without any additional capacitors at all (it is very far from the maximum power  possible, so no stress).

If you would draw the max. advertized current all the time you may notice differences between modules from different manufacturers due to varying component values and qualities. In some cases adding carefully chosen capacitors may lead to lower ripples or so.

If you need to optimize something in such a case, or want to integrate the ic yourself, just inspect the [datasheet](http://www.dcx-ic.com/uploads/soft/210625/1-210625131439.pdf) and follow the formulas and text carefully regarding capacitor values and their ESR.

Thank you @Justme for clarifying the OP's question.

Comment: I've read datasheets of different switching regulators.
most these datasheets have a fixed value of the capacitor and the capacitor that needs to be changed according to the input/output voltage
thank you i'll read datasheet more carefully.